# how to decide which one you are going to include in multiple linear regression if you have multiple related variables link to one predictor?

Tags: regression

I am using the multiple linear regression to work out if the glycaemic variables would influence my outcome while holding the body weight and menstrual cycle constant.

Here's the thing, for these glycaemic variables, I've measured several related factors, such as glucose peak and glucose nadir, which are highly correlated. So, I can't include all of these in one multiple linear regression. I'm considering running several multiple linear regressions to see if each factor affects my outcome. However, I wonder if it would increase the type 1 error if I performed so many calculations.

or what should I do if I want to explore the influence of each glycaemic factor on my outcome?

many thanks

Comment: Why can’t you include multiple correlated variables in your regression?

Comment: @Dave I suppose all the independent variables should not be correlated or it would violate the multicollinearity assumption

Comment: Standard regression theorems allow for correlated features, so what multicollinearity assumption do you mean?

Comment: There are so many functions that multiple regression can serve.  I'm sure it would be helpful for you to read up on them and to think through your own priorities for the analysis,  priorities which will probably dictate the way you go about the analysis.